# Colon operator meaning in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, web

Being new to angular 2 I am confused with this colon operator `:` like why and when should it be used? What does `hero:Hero` statement mean in:

```
onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `:` is related to `TypeScript`not `Angular 2`.

The two points are used (In this case) to specify the type of the parameter passed in the function.

**Examples**

*Number type :*

```
function add(x: number, y: number): number {
    return x + y;
}
```

*String type :*

```
function buildName(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

*Event type :*

```
class Handler {
    onClickGood(this: void, e: Event) {
        console.log('clicked!');
    }
}
```

*Class type :*

```
class Animal {
    numLegs: number;
}

class Bee extends Animal {
    keeper: BeeKeeper;
}

function buildName(A: Animal, B: Bee) {
    //code....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here 'hero' is a variable of type class 'Hero'.

This is something similar to

```
void onSelect(Hero hero){
       this.selectedHero = hero;
}
```

in Java,selectedHero being a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is like a try to make variables typed. so your `hero` variable have a `Hero` type, and your function returns nothing this is your `:void`. Same with that is is only for development as i think, anyways on the runtime stays only javasript.

Answer (score 0):

The colon `:` is what is referred to as a Type Annotation in TypeScript.

Type annotations can be used for variables, function parameters and function return values.

Variable Demonstration

```
let num: number = 1;
let str: string = 'foo';
let bool: boolean = false;
```

Function parameters Demonstration

```
public function doSomething( num: number, str: string, bool: boolean){
 /*some logic*/
}
```

Function return value Demonstration

```
public function doSomething(): void {
 //this function returns nothing
}

public function doSomethingElse(): boolean{
 // This function must return a boolean
 return true;
}
```